# Pytest runs twice in pre-commit

Tags: pytest, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Seems like pre-commit runs pytest tests twice. How to reproduce:

1. Install pytest, pytest-cov, pre-commit
2. Add `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   repos:
   - repo: local
     hooks:
       - id: unit_test
         name: Run unit pytest
         language: python
         language_version: python3
         entry: pytest tests/unit --cov=src/
         types: [ python ]
         fail_fast: true
         stages: [commit]

       - id: integr_tests
         name: Run integration pytest
         language: python
         language_version: python3
         entry: pytest tests/integration --cov=src/
         types: [ python ]
         fail_fast: true
         stages: [push]
   ```
3. Install pre-commit: `pre-commit install --hook-type pre-commit --hooktype pre-push`
4. Add tests to `tests/unit` folder. My structure
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4caYA.png)
5. `test_config_source.py` contains two dummy tests to fail:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS7qR.png)
6. Running pre-commit manually `pre-commit` leads to doubled failed tests:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhBjG.png)
7. Running same command separately from pre-commit `pytest tests/unit --cov=src/` is fine:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5fDg.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to start, running tests as part of pre-commit is a bad idea -- it's too slow and your contributors will get frustrated and turn the whole thing off

pre-commit is not really designed to run tests -- which is part of why you're running into issues with it.

pre-commit is designed to run things by [passing modified files as positional arguments](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) to the commands you configure.  you need to *fight the framework* here and turn that off

you can do that with the combination of `pass_filenames: false`, and `always_run: true`

but again, you shouldn't run your tests as part of pre-commit

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thanks Anthony. That helped.

And yes, you're right, using pytest with a pre-commit in any CI-CD is not a good enough idea. But I'm not going to use it there. pre-commit is only used in the local development environment to force unit tests to run on any code commit/change and huge integration tests once per push event. This is done in conjunction with code linters and code analyzers.

I would also like to thank you for your wonderful tool that helps us so much!